# PHP's scandir() returns false, can't locate directory

Tags: php, permissions, directory, scandir

I have a directory structure like this:

htdocs--->: dir.php, 
           img(rwxrw-rw-) ---> img1.jpg,
                               img2.jpg

but when I try to use `var_dump(scandir('/img'));`or `var_dump(scandir('/img/'));` in dir.php

it simply returns bool(false) and an error message saying it can't find /img/.

Why is this happening?

Comment: what is the root directory?

Comment: Don't you want a relative path `./img` ?

Comment: @DeDee Yes, I figured out myself I needed to remove the '/'s. now if only i could accept an answer ;)

Comment: grr.. was typing got interrupted, posted an answer.. and you solved your problem 48 seconds earlier. I need more coffee

Comment: @David it's all good, Duane posted one for you to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely /img  directory exists since the leading /  means it's at the root level of the hard drive. Try `./img`    The `./` means  THIS directory, eg, the directory the currently running PHP script is in.